# OpenNLP- Getting real score per category with DocumentCategorizer

Tags: java, opennlp, categorization

I'm using OpenNLP to categorize documents,
I use the code below:

```
DocumentCategorizerME categorizer = new DocumentCategorizerME(doccatModel);
double[] outcome = categorizer.categorize(say);
return categorizer.getBestCategory(outcome);
```

**I'm always getting outcomes that sum up to 1.**

The problem is that even if the match is poor - one of the categories seems to get a pretty good score just because it's just a little better than the others.

I tried the different methods that DocumentCategorizerME exposes, they all return the same result in different ways.

How can I get a good score and not just the distribution of probabilities?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are doing it right. Don't you get the best label after categorizer.getBestCategory(...)?
Suggestion: try other ML algorithms available in OpenNLP. For example, from command line trainer you can add ```-params lang/ml/PerceptronTrainerParams.txt```

Comment: It's not that it's not working, I do get the best category. The thing is that this category is the best but is not good enough. All I get is the probability and not a real score.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Collections.max(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(outcome))) > 0.3) {
            System.out.print(categorizer.getBestCategory(outcome));
```